# Silverstripe - 2 forms, 1 form action

Tags: php, forms, controller, silverstripe

I have 2 forms on the same controller but I am having trouble getting the 2nd form to write to the DB from the same form action. The first form writes no problem. I think my problem is getting the 2nd form to action.
How would I pass the 2nd forms data to be actioned? Can I call both functions from one action somehow?

```
public function CustomerForm() {        
    $form = BootstrapForm::create(
    $this,
    __FUNCTION__,
    FieldList::create(
        TextField::create("FirstName","FirstName")),            
        FieldList::create(
        FormAction::create("Action1","Save")->setStyle("success")),
        RequiredFields::create(array("FirstName"))  
        )->setLayout("horizontal")->addWell();          
        return $form;
    }

public function HiddenForm() { 
    $form = BootstrapForm::create(
    $this,
    __FUNCTION__,
    FieldList::create(
        HiddenField::create("CustomersID","CustomersID", $this->urlParams['ID'])),
        FieldList::create(
        FormAction::create("Action2","Save")->setStyle("success")),
        RequiredFields::create(array(""))   
        )->setLayout("horizontal")->addWell(); 
        return $form;
    }   

public static function Action1($data, $form) {
    $form->sessionMessage('Update successful', 'success');
    $submission = Customer::get()->byID($data["ID"]);  
    $form->saveInto($submission);
    $submission->write();
    return Controller::curr()->redirect("");
}

 public static function Action2($data, $form) {
    $submission = new SecondTable();
    $form->sessionMessage('The customer has been created', 'success');
    $form->saveInto($submission);
    return Controller::curr()->redirect("");
 }
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. I see two seperate actions in your codeAlso empty "RequiredFields" might cause problems.

Comment: I have left the required fields empty for now while getting it to work. I am wanting to call both actions but just from one form. Should I combine the two actions as one rather?

Comment: basically: yes. combine it if you want to do both with one button clicked.

Comment: That would be my next question. How would I pass the data from the 2nd form to that same function that the 1st form uses?

Comment: Why don't you call the second action from the first action with something like: `$submission->write(); self::Action2($data, $form);` as you seem to be passing in the same data and calling the same redirect? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but it looks like you may need some logic or it will create a customer each time the form is submitted if you always call both actions

Answer (score 0):

It is still unclear what you try to achieve, but in general you can pass all data in one form and handle it in steps.

```
public function CustomerForm() {
  $form = BootstrapForm::create(
    $this,
    __FUNCTION__,
    FieldList::create(
        TextField::create("FirstName","FirstName")),

        // this is unclear what is the relation to the current page
        HiddenField::create("CustomersID","CustomersID", $this->urlParams['ID'])),

    FieldList::create(
        FormAction::create("doSave","Save")->setStyle("success")),
    RequiredFields::create(array("FirstName"))
  )->setLayout("horizontal")->addWell();

  return $form;
}


public function doSave($data, $form) {
    // split update in steps
    $this->updateCustomer($data, $form);
    $this->updateSubmission($data $form);
    $form->sessionMessage('The customer has been created', 'success');
    return Controller::curr()->redirect("");
}

protected function updateCustomer($data, $form) {
    $customer = Customer::get()->byID($data["ID"]);
    $form->saveInto($customer);
    $customer->write();
}

protected function updateSubmission($data, $form) {
    $submission = new SecondTable();
    $form->saveInto($submission);
}
```